# Как настроить Qt для WebAssembly?

Tags: c++, qt, google-chrome, firefox, qml

Первым пунктом [новости](https://www.qt.io/blog/2019/06/19/qt-5-13-released) о выходе Qt 5.13 является объявление стабильного выпуска Qt for WebAssembly - поддержка исполнения Qt приложений в современных браузерах.

> Qt for WebAssembly lets you build Qt applications for web browsers and
>   is now fully supported.

Однако, я не вижу нужный мне kit в MaintenanceTool. Подскажите, где я могу получить инструментарий для сборки и какой компилятор поддерживается?

[image: MaintenanceTool]

Вроде бы, поддержку целевой платформы WebAssembly [завезли](https://habr.com/ru/post/454868/) в CLang, но у меня есть подозрения, что по датам Qt Group успели бы сделать комплект только для множества инструментов Emscripten.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала, вы не видите kit для сборки в WebAssembly, так как показываются только LTS (Long-term support) пакеты. Выберите чекбокс *"Latest releases"* и не забудьте нажать на кнопку *"Обновить"*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Идем дальше. Комплект *WebAssembly* действительно был разработан для инструментария Emscripten. Поэтому, следуя [инструкции](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/downloads.html), выполняем установку. Важно: исходя из [руководства](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_WebAssembly#Install_the_Emscripten_SDK) для Qt 5.13 нужна версия sdk ИМЕННО 1.38.27 64 разрядная. Обратите внимание, я выполняю установку **без** флага *"--embedded"*

```
git clone https://github.com/emscripten-core/emsdk.git
cd emsdk
./emsdk install sdk-1.38.27-64bit
brew cask install java
./emsdk activate sdk-1.38.27-64bit
source emsdk_env.sh
```

Проверяем:

```
emcc --version
emcc (Emscripten gcc/clang-like replacement) 1.38.27 (commit c56422590bb911603529052b7bd78e6ca3c9fa27)
Copyright (C) 2014 the Emscripten authors (see AUTHORS.txt)
This is free and open source software under the MIT license.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Отлично, установка выполнена. Далее, добавляем компилятор Emscripten C (Добавить -> Особый -> C). Примечание: путь к бинарнику после установки у меня получился следующий:

> /Users/tripolskypetr/emsdk/emscripten/1.38.27/emcc

[image: Emscripten C]

Тоже самое для Emscripten C++ (Добавить -> Особый -> C++), путь имеет следующий вид:

> /Users/tripolskypetr/emsdk/emscripten/1.38.27/em++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбираем компилятор C и C++, настроенные выше, комплекту.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первая сборка проекта будет идти очень долго. Ориентируйтесь на диспетчер задач, процесс *"asm2wasm"* будет в топе. Так же, на этапе проверки [wat](https://webassembly.org/docs/text-format/), будет зависать сам QtCreator (и кушать под 100%, это норма). Для тестовой сборки подойдет один из проектов в [этом](https://github.com/msorvig/qt-webassembly-examples) репозитории или шаблонный проект QML.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Примечание:** после успешной сборки Qt Creator не станет автоматически открывать собранное приложение. Сделать это придется мануально, развернув веб-сервер в директории сборки. Просто открыть браузером html документ не достаточно.

```
cd build-hello-world-Qt_5_13_1_WebAssembly-Debug/
python3 -m http.server
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]