# Как настроить комплект для Qt для WebAssembly?

Tags: qt, webassembly

Следуя [инструкции](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/downloads.html) а так же [различным статьям](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1034200/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-qt-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-webassembly) установил Emscripten SDK (emsdk).
Собственно, а дальше? Необходимо настроить Компиляторы и комплекты, но где лежит компилятор?
Методом научного тыка нашел вот такой путь к компилятору [image: скрин моего QtCretor]

Вроде QtCreator не ругается, но и не компилирует. Но уже в процессе создания проекта выдает вот такое:

```
Compiler feature detection failure!
Команда «/home/anton/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/libexec/qtcreator/clang/bin/clang -x c -E -dM -» аварийно завершилась.

Compiler feature detection failure!
Команда «/home/anton/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin/node -x c++ -E -dM -» завершилась с кодом 9.
/home/anton/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin/node: bad option: -x

Compiler feature detection failure!
Команда «/home/anton/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin/node -dumpmachine» завершилась с кодом 9.
/home/anton/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin/node: bad option: -dumpmachine

Compiler feature detection failure!
Команда «/home/anton/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin/node -dumpmachine» завершилась с кодом 9.
/home/anton/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin/node: bad option: -dumpmachine

Compiler feature detection failure!
Команда «/home/anton/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin/node -x c -E -dM -» завершилась с кодом 9.
/home/anton/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin/node: bad option: -x

Compiler feature detection failure!
Команда «/home/anton/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin/node -dumpmachine» завершилась с кодом 9.
/home/anton/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin/node: bad option: -dumpmachine

Compiler feature detection failure!
Команда «/home/anton/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin/node -print-search-dirs» завершилась с кодом 9.
/home/anton/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin/node: bad option: -print-search-dirs

Compiler feature detection failure!
Команда «/home/anton/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin/node -dumpmachine» завершилась с кодом 9.
/home/anton/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin/node: bad option: -dumpmachine

Compiler feature detection failure!
Команда «/home/anton/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin/node -print-search-dirs» завершилась с кодом 9.
/home/anton/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin/node: bad option: -print-search-dirs

Compiler feature detection failure!
Команда «/home/anton/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin/node -x c++ -E -dM -std=gnu++11 -fPIC -» завершилась с кодом 9.
/home/anton/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin/node: bad option: -x

Compiler feature detection failure!
Команда «/home/anton/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin/node -std=gnu++11 -fPIC -x c++ -E -v -» завершилась с кодом 9.
/home/anton/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin/node: bad option: -std=gnu++11
/home/anton/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin/node: bad option: -fPIC
/home/anton/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin/node: bad option: -x
```

А при попытке компиляции следующие ошибки:

```
13:29:25: Выполняются этапы для проекта Test04...
13:29:25: Настройки не изменились, этап qmake пропускается.
13:29:25: Запускается: «/bin/make» -j8
/home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/bin/qmake -o Makefile ../Test04/Test04.pro -spec linux-clang CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=qml_debug
/home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/bin/uic ../Test04/mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
clang++ -c -pipe -g -std=gnu++11 -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../Test04 -I. -I../../Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/include -I../../Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/include/QtWidgets -I../../Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/include/QtGui -I../../Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/include/QtCore -I. -I. -I../../Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/mkspecs/linux-clang -o main.o ../Test04/main.cpp
clang++ -c -pipe -g -std=gnu++11 -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../Test04 -I. -I../../Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/include -I../../Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/include/QtWidgets -I../../Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/include/QtGui -I../../Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/include/QtCore -I. -I. -I../../Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/mkspecs/linux-clang -o mainwindow.o ../Test04/mainwindow.cpp
/home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/bin/moc -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB --include /home/anton/QtProjects/build-Test04-Qt_5_15_2_WebAssembly-Debug/moc_predefs.h -I/home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/mkspecs/linux-clang -I/home/anton/QtProjects/Test04 -I/home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/include -I/home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/include/QtWidgets -I/home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/include/QtGui -I/home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/include/QtCore -I. -I/include/c++/9 -I/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9 -I/include/c++/9/backward -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include ../Test04/mainwindow.h -o moc_mainwindow.cpp
clang++ -c -pipe -g -std=gnu++11 -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../Test04 -I. -I../../Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/include -I../../Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/include/QtWidgets -I../../Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/include/QtGui -I../../Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/include/QtCore -I. -I. -I../../Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/mkspecs/linux-clang -o moc_mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.cpp
clang++ -ccc-gcc-name g++ -o Test04 main.o mainwindow.o test04_plugin_import.o moc_mainwindow.o   /home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/plugins/platforms/libqwasm.a /home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/lib/libQt5EventDispatcherSupport.a /home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/lib/libQt5FontDatabaseSupport.a /home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/lib/libqtfreetype.a /home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/lib/libQt5EglSupport.a /home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.a /home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/plugins/imageformats/libqicns.a /home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/plugins/imageformats/libqico.a /home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.a /home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.a /home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.a /home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/plugins/imageformats/libqwbmp.a /home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/plugins/imageformats/libqwebp.a /home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/lib/libQt5Widgets.a /home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/lib/libQt5Gui.a /home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/lib/libqtlibpng.a /home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/lib/libqtharfbuzz.a /home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/lib/libQt5Core.a /home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/lib/libqtpcre2.a   
/bin/ld: /home/anton/Qt/5.15.2/wasm_32/plugins/platforms/libqwasm.a: error adding symbols: file format not recognized
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Makefile:222: Test04] Error 1
13:29:27: Процесс «/bin/make» завершился с кодом 2.
Ошибка при сборке/развёртывании проекта Test04 (комплект: Qt 5.15.2 WebAssembly)
Во время выполнения этапа «Сборка»
13:29:27: Прошло времени: 00:02.
```

Это просто пустой проект, из одного окна, чтобы проверить компилятор.
Подскажите пожалуйста, может быть существует более подробная инструкция по настройке? Вообще не совсем понятно что ему надо, нутром чувствую что это какая-то мелочь, но заметная только опытному человеку , а не новичку.